# How do I know if I will need a storage migration along a forkless upgrade?

Tags: runtime, runtime-upgrade, frontier, migration, frontier-node-template

I have a blockchain running a version of Frontier from [september 2021](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/commit/3c23a72d33137455feca250225c87d504ef11a40), and want to upgrade it to the [latest commits](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/commit/bec24212467192203459cb500f23daad8182f815).
I'm prepared to do a forkless upgrade, but who do I know if I will need storage migration as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you have two ways to do this.

First: you can check [these pull-requests include runtime upgrade](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues?q=label%3AE1-runtimemigration%20), and then pick pull requests between your old version and your new version, check those pull requests carefully to see whether there is a pull request introduced storage migration.

Second: you can use [try-runtime](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/tools/try-runtime/) to see if there are on-runtime-upgrade logs appear.

Answer (score -1):

try to use the chain in --dev mode, then uploading the new wasm file, if it breaks the chain/stop producing blocks, then you need a storage migration